# No such table: sms.GroupTbl (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO sms.GroupTbl(txt,tel) VALUES (?,?)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to insert an sms into a db table.
But when I debug the program, I see this error

```
No such table: sms.GroupTbl (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO sms.GroupTbl(txt,tel) VALUES (?,?)
```

I have tried to reinstall the app and changing my DB name in the manifest, but neither of those solutions worked

DBAdapter.java

```
public class DBAdapter {

        String[] AllColumnForStudents = {
                KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_NAME
        };
    String[] AllColumnForGroupSms = {
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_txt,
            KEY_tel

    };
    static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_txt = "txt";
    static final String KEY_tel = "tel";
    static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
//MyDBCategory
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    static final String DATABASE_MAINTABLE = "main.GroupTbl";
    static final String DATABASE_Nametable = "sms.GroupTbl";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;
    private static final String CREATE_MAINTABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
          + DATABASE_MAINTABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
          + KEY_NAME + " text not null)";

    private static final String CREATE_Tsms = "CREATE TABLE "
            + DATABASE_Nametable + "(" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
             + KEY_txt + " varchar(500) NOT NULL, " + KEY_tel + " varchar(30) NOT NULL ) ";

        private static final String SQL_DELETE_TABLES =
                "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_MAINTABLE;
    private static final String SQL_DELETE_Tsms =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_Nametable;



    final Context context;

    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_MAINTABLE);
                db.execSQL(CREATE_Tsms);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

//            if (newVersion < oldVersion) {
//                Log.w("DBAdapter", "Updating database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
//                        + newVersion + " .Existing data will be lost.");

                db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_TABLES);
                db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_Tsms);
                onCreate(db);
            }
      //  }

    }

    public void onDelGroup()
    {
        //  db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        //  db.ExecNonQuery("delete from "+ DATABASE_Nametable);
       // db.delete(DATABASE_Nametable,null,null);
        SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM sms.GroupTbl");
       // db.close();

    }

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    **public long insertsms(String txt,String tel,String tabale)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_txt, txt);
        initialValues.put(KEY_tel, tel);
        long result=  db.insert(tabale, null, initialValues);
        return result;
    }**


    private List<ListAdapterSms> cursorToListsms(Cursor cursor) {
        List<ListAdapterSms> sms = new ArrayList<ListAdapterSms>();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                ListAdapterSms _sms = new ListAdapterSms();
                _sms.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                _sms.settxt(cursor.getString(1));
                _sms.settel(cursor.getString(2));
                sms.add(_sms);
            } ;
        }
        return sms;
    }

}
```

logcat

```
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1589)
                                                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1461)
                                                                                              at www.project_category.ir.project_category.DBAdapter.insertsms(DBAdapter.java:132)
                                                                                              at www.project_category.ir.project_category.MSmsActivity.RetSms(MSmsActivity.java:132)
                                                                                              at www.project_category.ir.project_category.MSmsActivity.onCreate(MSmsActivity.java:90)
                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 13:38:55.997 26429-26429/www.project_category.ir.project_category E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: sms.GroupTbl
12-21 13:38:56.027 26429-26429/www.project_category.ir.project_category E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting txt=قسمت سوم عطسه!
                                                                                          آخرين اثر مهران مديري 
                                                                                          عرضه انحصاري اينترنتي در ماي اپس
                                                                                          http://MyApps.ir
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These names are not valid:

```
static final String DATABASE_MAINTABLE = "main.GroupTbl";
static final String DATABASE_Nametable = "sms.GroupTbl";
```

Try using `_` in place of `.` in your table names.

```
static final String DATABASE_MAINTABLE = "main_GroupTbl";
static final String DATABASE_Nametable = "sms_GroupTbl";
```

Then uninstall and reinstall you app.
Or increase this constant

```
static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;
```

to a higher number

Comment: Nice answer . I guess it is perfect